# Why my regex accept also letters? ^[0-9\-\+_ ]

Tags: python, regex, django

Why my `regex` accept also letters? For example:

- test123 - it works (displays error message)
- 123abc - not working (does not display error message)

  ```
  test = forms.RegexField(
      max_length=15,
      regex=r'^[0-9\-\+_ ]',
      error_message=_(u"Only digits0-9 and +, _, -"),
      required=True,
      label=_(u'Test'))
  ```

It should accept string consisting of 0-9 and these special chars: +, _,-," "(space)

Comment: dont think the regex is your problem, i ran the regex using

f= re.findall('^[0-9\-\+_ ]', "test123")

and it does not accept the string

Comment: Why is this not tagged `regex`...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex is only testing the start of the string - in fact it is only testing the first character of the string. If `[0-9\-\+_ ]` is all you want in the whole string then stick a `+$` at the end:

```
regex=r'^[0-9\-\+_ ]+$'
```

This says that the whole string, start to finish, is only allowed to contain the characters inside the square brackets.

Comment: FYI: To allow empty string, use `*` quantifier: `regex=r'^[0-9\-\+_ ]*$'` (and you could use `\Z` instead of `$` to make sure no trailing newline gets in :) ). Also, no need escaping `+` inside the square brackets.